# Jest test breaks when component has DOM manipulation logic

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am unit testing my React app using Jest and Enzyme. I am running into a problem wherein when the component to be tested has DOM manipulation logic, my test cases break.

For instance, here is the hook of component I need to test:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.getElementById('complete').style.display = 'block';
}
```

On trying to shallow mount this component, I run into the below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
```

I googled around and found that I need to add document to my globals in jest. The painful thing is, I also need to defined each such property used in my app on the document as follows:

```
const mockUpObject = {
    focus: () => null,
    style:{
        display: ''
    }
};
global.document.getElementById = jest.fn(() => mockUpObject);
```

Why do we need it when by default jest runs in `jsdom` environment and hence simulates a DOM environment as if you were in the browser. Is there a cleaner way to make this work?

Comment: Is the element you are targeting part of the component you're testing/rendering? If so, you should apply the `style` property directly to the element rather than hitting the DOM directly. If it's part of a different component, then same concept applies and you want to know when this mounts then you can pass a callback via a prop. If it's out of the React rendering tree then you probably need to add it to the jsdom HTML fixture. You can use `document.body.appendChild(node)` in you test setup in Jest to do this.

Comment: @ourmaninamsterdam Its an old app & I can't change the code. Could you pls elaborate on last option?

Comment: So if the element you want to target is not part of your React tree you could add it to the DOM before your test. Some further info on this here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery . You will have to clear up the DOM afterwards if I can remember correctly.